# Unable to do wsdl generation by maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsgen

I am trying to build my project through maven(2.2.1) using jdk 1.7. But I am facing the issue when the goal wsgen runs. I go through various online issues but still unable to resolve this problem.

Below is my error log :

```
    Embedded error: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute wsgen
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute wsgen
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:148)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo.execute(MainWsGenMojo.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:101)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:182)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:213)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:186)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:186)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:111)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:318)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:130)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:236)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:124)
        at com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen.doMain(WsGen.java:74)
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:142)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
        at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3137)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:57)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:89)
        ... 35 more
```

Here is my parent pom with below configuration:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${java-compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/tmd-key.properties
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</name>
                            <location>${basedir}/eclipse_templates/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</name>
                            <location>${basedir}/eclipse_templates/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
                            </location>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
                        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-database</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${sqlplus.path}</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${db.work.dir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${db.schema_name}/${db.password}@${db.url_sqlplus}</argument>
                                <argument>@${db.wrapper_script}</argument>
                                <argument>${db.ref_data_schema}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <skip>${skip.build-db}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-publisher-database</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${sqlplus.path}</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${db.publisher.work.dir}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${db.schema_name}/${db.password}@${db.url_sqlplus}</argument>
                                <argument>@${db.publisher.wrapper_script}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <skip>${skip.build-db}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>       

            </plugin>

            <!-- Added BY Vibhas -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

     <!-- Commented BY Vibhas --> 
    <!-- <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${java.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins> -->
</build>
```

And below is the child pom which is trying to generate wsdl but fails to do so.

```
        <finalName>rds-web</finalName>

 <!-- <pluginManagement> By Vibhas-->
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11</version> -->

                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>

                      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                     <version>2.2</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.rds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntityLifeCycleServiceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleServiceV2_0</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_0.impl.EntityLifeCycleServiceEndpointV2_0
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntitySearchServiceV2_0</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_0.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpointV2_0
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntitySearchService</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.rds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityIsdSearchService</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.rds.isd.EntityIsdSearchServiceEndpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-RelationshipLifecycleWebservice</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.relationship.ws.endpoint.impl.RelationshipLifecycleWebserviceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-RelationshipSearchWebservice</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.relationship.ws.endpoint.impl.RelationshipSearchWebserviceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityBulkSearchServiceWebservice</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.rds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntityBulkSearchServiceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityJobServiceWebservice</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.cobam.rds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntityJobServiceEndpoint
                            </sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-ClientSearchServiceV2_0</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_0.impl.ClientSearchServiceV2_0Endpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-ClientSearchServiceV2_1</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_1.impl.ClientSearchServiceV2_1Endpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-ClientSearchServiceV1_0</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.impl.ClientSearchServiceV1_0Endpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-DrmSearchServiceV2_0Endpoint</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_0.impl.DrmSearchServiceV2_0Endpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl-EntityBulkServiceV2_0Endpoint</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>com.hex.client.ws.endpoint.v2_0.impl.EntityBulkServiceV2_0Endpoint</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/
                            </resourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <destDir></destDir>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--By Vibhas <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/tmd-key.properties
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                By Vibhas-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jazz
                        </artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jazz
                        </artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</name>
                            <location>/eclipse_templates/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</name>
                            <location>/eclipse_templates/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
                            </location>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
                        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>read_properties</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${profile.config}</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>write_properties</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputFile>src/test/resources/env.properties</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>

    </build>
```

After moving to maven 3.X and jaxws-maven-plugin version to 2.4.1. Below is the latest error log.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project rds-web: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project rds-web: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - ch
eck output
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:488)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.processSei(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:165)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.executeJaxws(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:155)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo.executeJaxws(MainWsGenMojo.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.execute(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:389)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :rds-web
```

Comment: Stop using old [Maven 2.2.1 cause it's End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html), start using Maven 3.X apart from that use http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/ (But this requires Maven 3.X)..

Comment: I am already using jaxws-maven-plugin but with Maven 2.2.1 version.

Comment: Current version on MojoHaus will not work with Maven 2.X and check the version you are using!

Comment: Which version of jaxws-maven-plugin should I use in Maven 3.X . Is it 2.3?

Comment: I tried with 1.9 jaxws-maven-plugin after updating my maven to 3.X  . But ended up having the below error:

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.9:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project erds-web: Failed to execute wsgen: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFa
ctory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.9:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project erds-web: Failed to execute wsgen
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

Comment: You are using 1.9 ? What do you expect? Why not using as i suggested 2.4.1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114732/discussion-between-vibhas-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: After trying 2.4.1 I am getting the below  issue again:

Comment: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project rds-web: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsgen (generate-wsdl-EntityLifeCycleService) on project rds-web: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed -

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.Still struggling with this issue.

Comment: I am using maven 3.3.9, java 1.8.0_121 and org.codehaus.mojo : jaxws-maven-plugin version 2.4.1 version. Still i am facing the same issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.