# Maven Plugin issue for Wsgen tag

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsgen

After tried several thing as posted by me on :

[Unable to do wsdl generation by maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831072/unable-to-do-wsdl-generation-by-maven-plugin)

I find the below issue after trying with several versions of mojo jaxws plugin which is already discussed in a site:

[Get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" though the class is in the classpath](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Get-quot-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-quot-though-the-class-is-in-the-classpath-td4778565.html)

So as per the suggestion I tried to add the tools jar in the plugin section just above org.codehaus.mojo.
I think this what it is suggested and one of the guy find the solution.

```
    <plugin>

                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>

                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin>
```

But trying that ended up having the below issue: Please provide any suggestion , if I am going wrong anywhere.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

    Missing:
    ----------
    1) jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command:
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jdk.tools -DartifactId=jdk.tools -Dversion=1.7 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=jdk.tools -DartifactId=jdk.tools -Dversion=1.7 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.9
        2) jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
  org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.9

from the specified remote repositories:
  releases (https://dsnexus.us.hibm.hex:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases),
  dsnexus-snapshots (https://dsnexus.us.hibm.hex:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots),
  R2 (http://dsnexus.us.hibm.hex:8081/nexus/content/groups/public),
  snapshots (https://dsnexus.us.hibm.hex:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots),
  jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss),
  dsnexus (https://dsnexus.us.hibm.hex:8081/nexus/content/groups/prd)



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Missing:
```

Comment: I tried with: <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>  but no success yet.

Comment: Any suggestion on : com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: [failed to localize] Exception bean names must be unique and must not clash with other generated classes